# order is disordered when importing .json to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

My problem is that I am importing multiple json in order object follows:

```
                      "historico" : [ 
                        {
                            "2007" : {
                                "01": {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "02" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "03" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "04" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "05" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "06" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "07" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "08" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "09" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "10" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "11" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                },
                                "12" : {
                                    "casos" : 0,
                                    "genero" : {
                                        "hombre" : 0,
                                        "mujer" : 0
                                    },
                                    "sintomas" : {
                                        "fiebre" : 0,
                                        "vomito" : 0
                                    }
                                }

                    }
                    }],
```

but to show the objects in the database MongoDB (robomongo use), all shown in disarray, by passing this ?, I am minding in the order all the time and are in disarray and do not understand why.

Comment: years and month in disarray..

Comment: ["Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)